# Why do binary trees have a node pointer inside of them, instead of just another node? Also, why is the creation function to this tree a pointer?

Tags: c++

This code snippet is an example I saw online:

```
struct Node {
    int data;
    Node* Left;
    Node* Right;
}

Node* CreateNode(int data) {
    Node* newNode = new Node();
    newNode->data = data;
    newNode->Left = newNode->Right = nullptr;
    return newNode;
}
```

I cannot understand, why are the nodes inside using pointers, instead of just simply the nodes themselves?

And also, why is the function for creating nodes returning a pointer?

Comment: If a node contains another node, this will result in an infinite amount of nodes. Does your computer have an infinite amount of RAM?

Comment: Pointers can be _null_ which allows the tree to have some kind of end.  You can not insist that every node contains another node, because the universe would not have enough memory to create one node.

Comment: What is the size of `struct node { int data; node child; }`?  to calculate the size of the node you need to know the size of the node.  So there is no way for the compiler to create such a thing.

Comment: Also, the creation function is _not_ a pointer.  It _returns_ a `Node*`, if that is what is making you think the function is a pointer.

Comment: As you're using C++ rather than C, why have `CreateNode` vs just giving the struct a constructor?

Comment: The purpose of a tree is not just to have nodes, but to store data.  Where would you put the data?

Comment: How would you link the nodes together, in the proper order, without some kind of pointer?

Comment: Additional syntax note: you need a semicolon after the struct.  `struct Node { ... };`